# why twilio is not reading xml from url?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-twiml

This is the code and i want twilio to read from a route which is a post route but it doesnt read xlm from there and there i want to get digit from a user and according to that input during call then i want the flow to work based on that input.

````
      .create({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://stormy-everglades-64562.herokuapp.com/voice',
        to: '+923047931504',
        from: '+17207344485'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));

   app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
   // Create TwiML response
   const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    twiml.gather(
    {
      numDigits: 1,
      action: '/gather',
    },
    gatherNode => {
      gatherNode.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.');
    }
   );

   // If the user doesn't enter input, loop
   twiml.redirect('/voice');

  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
 });```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
  app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
    // Create TwiML response
    const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
 
     const gather = twiml.gather(
     {
       numDigits: 1,
       action: '/gather',
     })
     gather.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.');
  
    // If the user doesn't enter input, loop
    twiml.redirect('/voice');

  // res.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());

  });
```